# create multiple sprites(nodes) with same texture swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite, skspritenode

So i'm trying to make a game and i have to generate a row of nodes that accelerates upward. But every time if I add the node I get an error (because the node already has a parent) obviously I added `Sprite.removeFromParent()`

[image]

in the image you can kind of see what I'm trying to implement.
Anyway the blocks also have to register how many times they're touched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question that is in the title:

Pretty simple, create an `SKTexture` and for each `SKSpriteNode` set the texture to that `SKTexture`.  The code for that would look something like this:

```
// Create the texture
var boxTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "boxImage")
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // Create box with defined texture
    var box = SKSpriteNode(texture: boxTexture);
    // Set position of box dynamically
    box.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(i * 20), CGFloat(512));
    // Name for easier use (may need to change if you have multiple rows generated)
    box.name = "box"+String(i);
    // Add box to scene
    addChild(box);
}
```

The problem that you are having in your description appears to be that you are only creating one `SKSpriteNode` when you need multiple to go across the bottom.  Simply use a `for` loop to create multiple, and add them all to the scene (basically, the same code from above).  You may wish to give them all `name` properties in order to figure out which box is which later on (if you don't store them as global variables).  Make sure to change around the naming if you have multiple rows of boxes moving at the same time.